# javascript inheritance strangeness

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Why does the "Cat.prototype = new Mammal()" line below not work inside the Cat() function, but it works outside the Cat() function?

```
function Mammal() {
  Mammal.prototype.hasHair = function() { return true; }
}

alert( new Mammal().hasHair() ); // dispays true here

function Cat() {
  Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
}

try {
  new Cat().hasHair(); // doesn't work. why?
} catch ( err ) {
  alert('error'); // displays error here
}

Cat.prototype = new Mammal(); // same line as inside Cat() function

alert( new Cat().hasHair() ); // now it works
```

I tried this with several different javascript implementations, so I doubt it is an implementation idiosyncrasy. I wonder about this mostly out of curiousity, but also just for organization, I would like to define about Cats inside Cat's function, not spread out all over everywhere.

Comment: Does it really matter? This is a pattern you should never be using anyway.

Comment: ...but to answer, the second you do `new Cat()`, you've created an object that inherits from the current prototype object. Then in the constructor you *replace* the prototype object with a new one. This replacement doesn't affect the object you've already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `prototype` members are passed to the object instance **before** constructor is executed.

http://jsfiddle.net/vSDbB/

```
function Mammal() {
  Mammal.prototype.hasHair = function() { return true; }
}

function Cat() {
    Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
}

new Cat();
alert(new Cat().hasHair());
```

So the code above will work, but if you commented first `new Cat();` line it wouldn't since on the `new Cat().hasHair()` line Cat's prototype doesn't have `hasHair()` method

Comment: Several people here explained this quite well, But Zerkms answered so succinctly that I had to give the thumbs-up to him. Wish I could choose several answers to accept.

Comment: @user1717831: haha, the only reason for succinctness is that I cannot express my thoughts well due to lack of English knowledge ))

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you execute `new Cat`, an empty object which inherits from `Cat.prototype` is created. What is `Cat.prototype`? It's an empty object since you have not modified it yet.

Inside the constructor, you are assigning `Cat.prototype = new Mammal();`. The next instance of `Cat` will inherit from this `Mammal` instance. Creating a second instance though will also create another `Mammal` instance, from which the third `Cat` instance inherits, and so on.

You end up with this inheritance chain (`catX` is the x-th instance of `Cat` and `mammalX` is the x-th instance of `Mammal`):

```
cat0 -> Object
cat1 -> mammal0 -> Mammal.prototype
cat2 -> mammal1 -> Mammal.prototype
...
```

Each `Cat` instance has its own prototype, which is somehow contrary to what prototypes are used for (sharing common code). It might not look like such a big deal, but it has several consequences, including:

- Increases memory usage: (nearly) each `Cat` instance has a corresponding `Mammal` instance, so you have `2N` objects instead of `N + 1`.
- Inheritance tests break: `instanceof` works by comparing prototypes, and since the prototype of `cat0` is different than `Cat.prototype` (after creating multiple instances), `cat instanceof Cat` will yield `false`.

The inheritance chain you really want is:

```
cat0 -> Mammal.prototype
cat1 -> Mammal.prototype
cat2 -> Mammal.prototype
...
```

---

Never assign values to the prototype (or overwrite the prototype) inside the constructor function. The constructor function should only set **instance specific** properties (in some cases you might want to change static properties, but these are less common).

Set up the prototype outside the constructor function:

```
function Mammal() {}       
Mammal.prototype.hasHair = function() { return true; }

function Cat() {
    Mammal.apply(this, arguments);
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```

`Object.create` creates an object inheriting from the object you pass as argument. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused. What do you actually expect?

You're assigning a *function* into the *prototype chain* from `Cat`, but you do so on invocation of the constructor function. If you call it like `new Cat().hasHair()`, the *object of invocation* doesn't know about that function at all.

**You need to extend the `.prototype` before you actually invoke the constructor function.**

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code so it can achieve your goal. The following code creates a base class then a sub class in the same style you are attempting to do it.

```
function Mammal() {
  this.hasHair = function() { return true; }
}

alert( new Mammal().hasHair() ); // dispays true here

function Cat() {
   Mammal.call(this);

}

try {
  alert( new Cat().hasHair() ); // dispays true here
} catch ( err ) {
  alert('error'); // should not fire
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

because you are overwriting the prototype on every instantiation. Javascript doesn't really have inheritance.

when you do

```
function Mammal() {
    Mammal.prototype.hasHair = function() { return true; }
}
new Mammal().hasHair();
```

it means

1. use `Mammal` as a constructor and instantiate a `new Mammal` type object
2. overwrite the prototype of `Mammal` every time you do this

but if you do this:

```
function Cat() {
}
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
new Cat().hasHair();
```

it means

1. let the `Cat` constructor's prototype be a `new Mammal type object`
2. instantiate a `new Cat type object` that 'inherited' a `hasHair()` method through the `Mammal` 'class'

hope this helps.

Comment: JavaScript has prototypal inheritance, which is a form of inheritance ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling yes yes, my bad, I wasn't specific. I should have wrote doesn't have inheritance in the 'classical sense'? if that's right.

Comment: @tenshou—yes, just delete the second sentence of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of a function (that acts as a class), is what a new object is copied from when it's created.  You shouldn't be setting properties on the prototype in the constructor.

Either this:

```
function Mammal() {
}
Mammal.prototype.hasHair = function(){ return true };
```

OR this:

```
function Mammal() {
    this.hasHair = function(){ return true }
}
```

Comment: New objects aren't "copied" from their constructor's prototype, they inherit from it.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  I was trying to choose a word that conveyed the state of the object relative to its class's prototype at the moment it is instantiated.  If you change an object, it doesn't change its prototype.  Almost like it's a... hmm, what's the word?